# Android Runnable - Thread goes in sleeping state once code is executed, does not terminate

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpool, profiler

I am creating a thread pool for running operations in background in an android app.
Following is the code to create the thread pool and perform operations. Thread pool will be created only once but function gets called multiple times so multiple runnables are submitted to executor.

```
fun performOperation(){
    if(executorPool == null)
        executorPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
    val runnable = Runnable{
                           //operations
                           }
    val future = executorPool!!.submit(runnable)
}
```

I am using cachedThreadPool. by definition it says:

> Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are available. These pools will typically improve the performance of programs that execute many short-lived asynchronous tasks. Calls to execute will reuse previously constructed threads if available. If no existing thread is available, a new thread will be created and added to the pool. Threads that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and removed from the cache.

My expectation is once the operations are executed, my runnable thread should be terminated automatically after 60 seconds, but when I check in CPU profiler, runnable threads generated from here keep on increasing the times performOperation() function is called.
In CPU profiler, I can see runnable threads going in sleeping state and not terminating(in Dead state).

I want to reduce the Thread count here, please guide me how should I proceed or how should I handle this.

Comment: *My expectation is once the operations are executed, my runnable thread should be terminated automatically* ... your expectations are wrong ... or you have to add your definition of *operations are executed* ... executor runs `Runnable.run` on free thread until it is finished ... so for me operation is `Runnable.run` ... so there is no termination (unless executor is terminated) - if you block `Runnable.run` it will run indefinitely

Comment: The job of a thread pool is to provide threads for jobs. When a job is finished it will be returned to the pool to be reused by the next job.

Comment: I am using cachedThreadPool, by definition it says thread will be removed after 60 seconds from pool

Comment: it will be removed FROM CACHE ID IT'S NOT USED ... if you are blocking it in `Runable.run` it woudn't ...

Answer (score 1):

Try logging active thread count and thread pool size everytime you run an operation to be sure if that is the issue.

This is how I did it

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var executorPool:ExecutorService? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        performOperation()

        var button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener {

            val runnable = Runnable{
                Thread.sleep(1000)
                Log.e("msg","ok!")
                if (executorPool is ThreadPoolExecutor) {
                    Log.e("msg",(executorPool as ThreadPoolExecutor).poolSize.toString())
                }
            }

            val future = executorPool!!.submit(runnable)

        }


    }

    fun performOperation(){
        if(executorPool == null)
            executorPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()

    }
}
```

This is my logcat

```
2022-06-20 12:58:36.572 12493-12526/com.example.testkotlin E/msg: ok!
2022-06-20 12:58:36.572 12493-12526/com.example.testkotlin E/msg: 1
2022-06-20 12:58:38.699 12493-12526/com.example.testkotlin E/msg: ok!
2022-06-20 12:58:38.699 12493-12526/com.example.testkotlin E/msg: 3
2022-06-20 12:58:38.867 12493-12529/com.example.testkotlin E/msg: ok!
2022-06-20 12:58:38.867 12493-12529/com.example.testkotlin E/msg: 3
2022-06-20 12:58:39.055 12493-12530/com.example.testkotlin E/msg: ok!
2022-06-20 12:58:39.055 12493-12530/com.example.testkotlin E/msg: 3
2022-06-20 12:58:43.394 12493-12530/com.example.testkotlin E/msg: ok!
2022-06-20 12:58:43.394 12493-12530/com.example.testkotlin E/msg: 3
2022-06-20 12:59:20.868 12493-12530/com.example.testkotlin E/msg: ok!
2022-06-20 12:59:20.868 12493-12530/com.example.testkotlin E/msg: 3
2022-06-20 12:59:44.221 12493-12530/com.example.testkotlin E/msg: ok!
2022-06-20 12:59:44.221 12493-12530/com.example.testkotlin E/msg: 1
```

Here you can see after 1 minute thread pool size is 1 again after going upto 3

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tryed kotlin coroutines?
It faster and you doun't need use pool.
[Coroutines basics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html)
.
Android include scopes for work in fragment like **lifecycleScope** and in viewModel
like **viewModelScope**. 
 Also you can create scope with Dispatchers **CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)** or connect in your coroutine **launch(Dispatchers.IO){}**
You shold do something hard in Dispatchers.IO and change your views in **Dispatchers.Main**

You can read more here [developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines)

You doun't need thread pool.
Just compare performance.

```
fun main() {
val count = 100000

thread(count)

//  runBlocking {
//      coroutine(count)
//  }
}

private fun thread(count: Int){
    for (i in 0 until count) {
        thread {
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            println(i)
        }
    }
}

private fun CoroutineScope.coroutine(count: Int){
    for (i in 0 until count) {
        launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            delay(1000)
            println(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though, at all.